# Getting translated records in CommandController

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.7.x

I've searched and debugged the last couple of days how to obtain the
translated version of a DomainModel object in a CommandController in Typo3 v8.7.

In Typo3 4.5/4.7 I've done the following:
- input: DomainModel in default language
- build a query that finds the record with the l10n_parent matching the
  given domain model
- obtain a new domain model with the desired sys_language_uid

Unfortunately this does not work in Typo3 v8.7 any more. I always get
the domain model for the default language.

I've traced this down to the method `Typo3DbBackend::doLanguageAndWorkspaceOverlay`
called via `Typo3DbBackend::getObjectDataByQuery`

The query returns the correct (translated) row (seen in the debugger and also the mysql query log), but then the variable
`$row` gets overwritten in `doLanguageAndWorkspaceOverlay` no matter how I
set the querySettings `setLanguageOverlayMode` and `setLanguageMode`.

So what is the correct way to get a translated domain model in a
CommandController?

**UPDATE:**

I think I'm a step further. If I add `->setQueryLanguage(1)` to the query settings, `doLanguageAndWorkspaceOverlay()` tries to fetch the translated record for language = 1. But in order to succeed I need to trick the `FrontendGroupRestriction` class by setting `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->gr_list = "0,-2";`.

The array returned by `doLanguageAndWorkspaceOverlay()` now contains all translated entries, except the `uid`, which is still the `uid` from the record in the main language. The `uid` of the translated record is stored in `_LOCALIZED_UID`.

Now my problem now is that I still get the record in the main laguage because `DataMapper->mapSingleRow()` (called via `DataMapper->map()`) has some kind of object cache and thus returns the object in the default language (because the `uid` is still the one of the record in the main language).

All this seems a little hackish. So again my question: what is the correct way to get a translated domain model in a CommandController?

thanks,
mika

p.s.: I've set up the second language in the backend and creating a translated record works just fine. My question is just how to I get an existing translated record in a CommandController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**alternative solution:**

based on the solution above, I decided that I can do almost everything
on my own. So what I do now is

i) create an independend querybuilder for the according table:

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($tableName);`
```

ii) select the record with the desired l10n_parent and sys_language_uid

```
$query = $queryBuilder->select('*')
         ->from($tableName)
         ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('sys_language_uid', $langId))
         ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('l10n_parent', $parentUid))
         ->execute();
```

iii) fetch all records into an array

```
$rows = $query->fetchAll();
```

iv) invoke the DataMapper manually to get the object

```
$dataMapper = $this->objectManager->get(DataMapper::class);
$translated = $dataMapper->map($className, $rows);
```

I know it has nothing to do with the ModelRepository any more, but it
works quite fine for now...

that's all folks

Comment: Here the mm table is still getting non translated. Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the issue described above:

To avoid invoking the DataMapper as part of the query from
Typo3DbBackend, I used a raw query (argument for `->execute()`) and get
back an array, that already went through language overlay etc.

*BUT:* in
the array the '_LOCALIZED_UID' is still available. So I overwrite the
uid with the value from '_LOCALIZED_UID' and invoke the DataMapper
manually. Quite cumbersome and very hackish to overcome the Typo3
backend shortcomings...